# Allow parameters to fill form fields

Tags: nginx

Nginx is sending a 403 Forbidden when I attempt to use a parameter in my URLs. I want URLs like this one to fill the URL field on any page on the site.

`https://example.com/?url=https://example.com`

I am not handy with nginx, so any detailed steps to change this would be great. I'm guessing I have an nginx directive somewhere that disallows parameters.

***UPDATE***

`https://example.com/?url=example.com`

Does not 403, so possibly this is related to the https:// in the parameter throwing the 403.

Comment: There is no nginx directive that disables/enables parameters. Does it 403 for all parameters like `foo=bar` or just URLs? You likely have a file permission issue with the resource you're accessing; check if nginx's user/group is allowed to access the resource.

Comment: foo=bar works, i.e, does not 403. Also, ?url=example.com without https does not 403, although it does not fill the form field. So it maybe something related to the https:// , maybe encoding?

Comment: I checked a local nginx installation, other nginx websites, and chckr.co: it seems like just chckr.co is blocking the strings `https://` and `http://` but not `foo://`. I noticed it's running on CF (which is a nginx proxy), and no other CF site does this. If this is a shared hosting environment then it must be their own addition to block off proxies. Whatever it is you can get around this by URL encoding your values, `?url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com`.

Comment: I literally just found the cause - my 7G WAF is blocking those URLs as bad requests. I also saw your testing of the https:// etc as bad requests. I'm glad you posted the comment here so I know that was not a bot. So thanks - I will either encode the URLs or find a way to allow https through the WAF.